# User Authentication error - Passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Im using passport.js (local strategy) to authenticate users but I am getting the following error:

```
Unhandled "error" event. (Incorrect arguments)
```

**Detailed Error Message:**

[image]

**index.js file:**

```
const {register: registerUser, login: loginUser} = require('../controllers/authentication');

// login
router
.route('/login')
.post(loginUser);
```

**Authentication.js file:**

```
// login function
let login = (req,res) => {

if(!req.body.email || !req.body.password){
    sendJsonResponse(res, 400, {"message": "All fields required"});
    return;
}

passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {

    let token;

    if(err){
        sendJsonResponse(res, 404, err);
        return;
    }

    if(user){
        token = user.generateJwt();
        sendJsonResponse(res, 200, {
           "token": token
        });
    } else {
        sendJsonResponse(res, 401, info);
    }
})(req,res);
};
```

**Passport.js File:**

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('Users');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',

}, function (email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({'email': email}, function(err, user) {
        if(err){
            return done(err);
        }

        if(!user){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect Username.'});
        }

        if(!user.validPassword(password)){
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect Password.'});
        }
        return done(null, user)
    });
   }
));
```

I can't seem to figure out what the issue might be. I've tried checking `typeof` for both email and password and they are indeed `Strings`. Does anybody know what could be the issue.

Comment: The second argument of `passport.authenticate()` should be an object, not a function.

Comment: you have to require your model, if it's not defined in the passport.js file